# Crear una columna condicional en base a otro DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy intentando crear una nueva columna en `df1=pd.DataFrame()` (de gran tamaño):

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | g |
| 2 | d |
| 1 | d |
| 3 | h |

donde, cuando se cumpla una condición a través de `np.where(df1.A==1,)`, busque el valor de B en `df2=pd.Dataframe()`

| B | C |
| --- | --- |
| g | r4 |
| d | o4 |
| h | i7 |
| m | z1 |

, arrojandome el valor de la columna C en el caso que corresponda, y caso contrario sea 0.

Es decir, mi resultado deseado es:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | g | r4 |
| 2 | d | 0 |
| 1 | d | o4 |
| 3 | h | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Tal como comentó @Abulafia (Pero no lo incluyó en su respuesta), esto se resuelve muy fácilmente con un [`pandas.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).

Lo único que hay que hacer es utilizar la columna "B" del segundo dataframe como índice al hacer el `join` y esto copiará todos los valores de "C" en el primer `dataframe`. Ojo, esto incluye las filas donde "A" es igual a 2.

Para únicamente dejar los valores de "C" cuando `"A" == 1` utilizamos [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,1,2], 'B':['g','d','d','h']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['g','d','h','m'], 'C': ['r4', 'o4', 'i7', 'z1']})

# Creamos un join de df2 en df1
df1 = df1.join(df2.set_index('B'), on='B')

# Seleccionamos las filas donde A es diferente de 1
# y asignamos 0 en la columna C
df1.loc[df1['A'] != 1, 'C'] = 0
print(df1)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
   A  B   C
0  1  g  r4
1  2  d   0
2  1  d  o4
3  2  h   0
```

Comment: ¡Eso era lo que yo tenía en la punta de la lengua! :-) Pero yo añadiría al final un `df1.C.fillna()` para cubrir el caso en que haya una fila en que A=1, pero el valor de B no esté en el otro dataframe, por ejemplo que el B de la tercera fila valga "j" (lo que produciría un NaN en C)

Comment: El `fillna` yo lo agregaría directamente en la fila del `join` para no tener una línea de código extra, pero no lo puse porque desconozco las intenciones del OP.

Comment: Las intenciones estan en el enunciado, copiar el valor de C "en el caso de que corresponda y en caso contrario _sea 0_" Yo me refería a usar fillna(0)

Answer (score 0):

La solución que se me ha ocurrido es bastante compleja, y no dejo de pensar que lo que buscas se parece a un `.join()`, pero no acabo de verlo.

Lo que se me ha ocurrido es lo siguiente:

```
# Primero extraemos de df1 los valores de la columna "B" 
# para las filas en que la columna "A" vale 1
seleccion = df1[(df1.A==1)].B

# Ahora buscamos en df2 esos valores en la columna "B" 
# y extraemos los correspondientes valores de "C"
# Para esto, temporalmente usamos "B" como index en df2
result = df2.set_index("B").loc[seleccion.tolist()].C

# Ahora asignamos en df1, en las filas antes encontradas
# por la "selección", y en una nueva columna "C" los valores
# que hemos encontrado en el paso anterior
df1.loc[seleccion.index, "C"] = result.values

# Esto solo asigna las filas indicadas, dejando el resto con NaN
# por lo que finalmente rellenamos con ceros esos NaN
df1["C"] = df1["C"].fillna(0)
```

Ejecutando ésto sobre tus dataframe de ejemplo sale el resultado que buscabas:

```
   A  B   C
0  1  g  r4
1  2  d   0
2  1  d  o4
3  3  h   0
```

pero no estoy del todo seguro de si funcionará en casos más generales. Por ejemplo, fallará si alguno de los valores de B buscados en df2 no apareciera (por ejemplo, que df1 contuviera una "j" en la columna "B", tercera fila)